# How can I store function pointers in an array?

Tags: arrays, function-pointers, rust

How do you stick functions (or function pointers) into an array for testing purposes?

```
fn foo() -> isize { 1 }
fn bar() -> isize { 2 }

fn main() {
    let functions = vec![foo, bar];
    println!("foo() = {}, bar() = {}", functions[0](), functions[1]());
}
```

This code in the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e89a4cbd1b7f2b73235c624a41167bc8&version=stable&backtrace=0)

This is the error code I get:

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `fn() -> isize {foo}`,
    found `fn() -> isize {bar}`
(expected fn item,
    found a different fn item) [E0308]

    let functions = vec![foo, bar];
                              ^~~
```

Rust is treating my functions (values) as different types despite having the same signatures, which I find surprising.

Comment: Curiously, this is only a limitation of `vec![]` (actually, [it's a problem with `box [...]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632524/why-does-boxing-an-array-of-function-pointers-with-box-syntax-only-work-with-a)). You can easily create an array or slice of function pointers: `let arr = [foo, bar]`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At some point recently, each function was given its own, distinct type for... reasons that I don't recall.  Upshot is that you need to give the compiler a hint (note the type on `functions`):

```
fn foo() -> isize {
    1
}
fn bar() -> isize {
    2
}
fn main() {
    let functions: Vec<fn() -> isize> = vec![foo, bar];
    println!("foo() = {}, bar() = {}", functions[0](), functions[1]());
}
```

You can also do this like so:

```
let functions = vec![foo as fn() -> isize, bar];
```

Comment: Thanks! It's always a shame to see a use case get harder; I hope they had some reason for this breaking change.  Annotating the type on the left hand side isn't so bad ~if you know how to write function type signatures, which I did not yet.

Comment: "fn items" have a benefit: It avoids a call through a function pointer which is a virtual call. LLVM may *devirtualize* that call in an optimization pass, but fn item and unboxed closure calls should always be direct, without relying on the optimizer to get it right.

Comment: You can place them in an array, but you have to have a bit more casting: `let functions = [foo as fn() -> isize, bar as fn() -> isize];` or even `let functions: [fn() -> isize; 2] = [foo, bar];`. You could also make a slice `let functions: &[fn() -> isize] = &[foo, bar];`.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once. Without inheritance in the language I completely forgot about the idea that it might be inferring too specific a type, and need to be reined in. Spent several frustrated hours on this....