# Expected closure, found a different closure

Tags: rust

`A` is a structure which contains a vector of `B`. `A` implements the `add_b` method which adds a `B` instance to the list of `B`. `B` contains a closure property `f`.

If I add one `B` to the vector with `add_b`, it's OK. If I add two vectors with `add_b`, I got an error saying the two closures are different. Here is a minimal example:

```
// A struct...
struct A<F> {
    b_vec: Vec<B<F>>, // A vector of B
}

// ...and its implementation
impl<F> A<F>
where
    F: Fn(),
{
    fn new() -> A<F> {
        A { b_vec: Vec::new() }
    }

    fn add_b(&mut self, b: B<F>) {
        self.b_vec.push(b);
    }
}

// B struct...
struct B<F> {
    f: F,
}

// ...and its implementation
impl<F> B<F>
where
    F: Fn(),
{
    fn new(f: F) -> B<F> {
        B { f: f }
    }
}

// I add two B (with their closures arguments) in A
fn main() {
    let mut a = A::new();
    a.add_b(B::new(|| println!("test")));
    a.add_b(B::new(|| println!("test2")));
}
```

This code results in:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:39:20
   |
39 |     a.add_b(B::new(|| println!("test2")));
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected closure, found a different closure
   |
```

How can I add multiple `B` with their different closures to `A`'s `b_vec`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's always worth taking a look at the **full** compiler output:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:39:20
   |
39 |     a.add_b(B::new(|| println!("test2")));
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected closure, found a different closure
   |
   = note: expected type `[closure@src/main.rs:38:20: 38:39]`
              found type `[closure@src/main.rs:39:20: 39:40]`
   = note: no two closures, even if identical, have the same type
   = help: consider boxing your closure and/or using it as a trait object
```

Especially helpful:

- > no two closures, even if identical, have the same type
- > consider boxing your closure and/or using it as a trait object

We can simplify your example further by removing the type `B` altogether. Then the only task is to save a vector of closures. As the compiler tells us, no two closures have the same type, but `Vec` is a homogeneous data structure, meaning that every item in it has the same type.

We can work around that restriction by introducing one level of indirection. As the compiler suggests, this can either be done by trait objects or boxing (the latter kind of includes the first one). The corresponding types would look like this:

- `Vec<&dyn Fn()>` (reference to trait objects)
- `Vec<Box<dyn Fn()>>` (trait object in a box)

In your example you want to *own* all closures, thus the correct choice is to box all closures, as `Box<T>` is an owning wrapper while references only borrow stuff.

A fully working example:

```
struct A {
    b_vec: Vec<B>,
}

impl A {
    fn new() -> A {
        A { b_vec: Vec::new() }
    }

    fn add_b(&mut self, b: B) {
        self.b_vec.push(b);
    }
}

struct B {
    f: Box<dyn Fn()>,
}

impl B {
    fn new<F>(f: F) -> B
    where
        F: Fn() + 'static,
    {
        B { f: Box::new(f) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A::new();
    a.add_b(B::new(|| println!("test")));
    a.add_b(B::new(|| println!("test2")));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! FYI: I think I understood what you wrote, now fixing my code is not so easy (I'm still a beginner). I simplified my code by removing `B` (ok, check), then tried to add `Vec<Box<F>>` in struct declaration, then added `Box::new(...)` in `add_b` and still have the same error. Not sure to understand what I missed, I still have to dig.

Comment: Rust playground here: http://play.integer32.com/?gist=74fa771c562d30c541db54b2e8cf8ec8

Comment: Might be worth nothing that if the closures actually do not capture any variable from the environment, then `fn()` is an appropriate type and does not require boxing.

Comment: @rap-2-h You literally have to write `Vec<Box<Fn()>>` and not `F`. That's important. This way we do remove all type parameters. Here is a version that works: http://play.integer32.com/?gist=b387fb2439171547470e0047ec0f8f14  (this does the boxing outside of `add_b`; you can do it inside by adding a type parameter to the function, not `A`)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/29371914/155423 ?

Comment: @Shepmaster I've found that one, too, but *I* don't think it's a duplicate. OP in the linked question already uses `Box` and needs to specify the concrete trait-type. Here it's more or less the other way around...

Answer (score 6):

In this specific example, you can avoid a *trait object* by using a *function pointer* instead:

```
struct B {
    f: fn(),
}

impl B {
    fn new(f: fn()) -> B {
        B { f: f }
    }
}
```

The rest of [Lukas Kalbertodt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39083692/155423) is unchanged:

```
struct A {
    b_vec: Vec<B>,
}

impl A {
    fn new() -> A {
        A { b_vec: Vec::new() }
    }

    fn add_b(&mut self, b: B) {
        self.b_vec.push(b);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A::new();
    a.add_b(B::new(|| println!("test")));
    a.add_b(B::new(|| println!("test2")));
}
```

This is only valid because your closures do not capture any environment. The Rust compiler is thus able to "promote" them to full functions and then take references to the implicit function.