# Rust no two closures, even if identical, have the same type

Tags: rust, closures

How do to put two closures with the same definition into a `Vec`?

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push(Box::new(|| println!("test")));
    vec.push(Box::new(|| println!("test2")));
    
    vec.iter().for_each(|f| (f)());
}
```

Which failed on compiling with following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:23
  |
3 |     vec.push(Box::new(|| println!("test")));
  |                       -- the expected closure
4 |     vec.push(Box::new(|| println!("test2")));
  |              -------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected closure, found a different closure
  |              |
  |              arguments to this function are incorrect
  |
  = note: expected closure `[closure@src/main.rs:3:23: 3:25]`
             found closure `[closure@src/main.rs:4:23: 4:25]`
  = note: no two closures, even if identical, have the same type
  = help: consider boxing your closure and/or using it as a trait object
```

Comment: Need to point the common type so rust can do the coersion, `let mut vec: Vec<Box<dyn Fn()>> = Vec::new();`  . otherwise Rust will assume it like `Vec<Box<SomeAnonymousConcreteType>>`

Comment: Found this duplicate [Expected closure, found a different closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083375/expected-closure-found-a-different-closure) by putting your title into the search bar...

Comment: @cafce25 I found that question before asking this question, but haven't gotten a solution for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must explicitly tell that `vec` holds boxed trait objects:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut vec: Vec<Box<dyn Fn()>> = Vec::new();
    vec.push(Box::new(|| println!("test")));
    vec.push(Box::new(|| println!("test2")));
    
    vec.iter().for_each(|f| (f)());
}
```

On the other hand you can leave it as it and "cast" boxed object with `as` keyword:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push(Box::new(|| println!("test")) as Box<dyn Fn()>);
    vec.push(Box::new(|| println!("test2")));
    
    vec.iter().for_each(|f| (f)());
}
```

note that you have to do it only once, since now rust will infer that type of `vec` is indeed `Vec<Box<dyn Fn()>>`, and further pushing will know to do this cast automatically.

Comment: I am fairly certain that you can hint to the compiler that it needs to coerce, and have it find the right type with `as _` instead of giving the full type. For those all important keystroke savings

Comment: @PatientPenguin unfortunately this won't work and will result with the following error `an "as" expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object`. This makes sense, because rust cannot know _which_ trait objects you want to store (`dyn Fn()`, `dyn FnOnce()`, `dyn FnMut()`, or something else entirely).

Comment: Oh you are totally right, my bad!

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze also for this specific case since the closures don't close over anything you don't have to box them, you can just coerce them to static function pointers (`fn()`).