# How do I make a dispatch table in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to build a simple RPN calculator, and I've got the basics working. I'd like to make a [dispatch table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table) to implement the various calculator functions. If I were doing this in Perl, I would write something like:

```perl
my %ops = (
  '+' => sub { +shift + +shift; },
  '-' => sub { +shift - +shift; },
  '*' => sub { +shift * +shift; },
  '/' => sub { +shift / +shift; }
);
```

or in JavaScript:

```
let ops = {
    "+": (a, b) => a + b,
    "-": (a, b) => a - b,
    "*": (a, b) => a * b,
    "/": (a, b) => a / b
};
```

This is what I've tried so far in Rust:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    println!("Going to call +");

    let dispatch = HashMap::new();

    dispatch.insert(String::from("+"), |a, b| a + b);
    dispatch.insert(String::from("-"), |a, b| a - b);

    let plus = dispatch.get(&String::from("+"));
    println!("2 + 3 = {}", plus(2, 3));

    let minus = dispatch.get(&String::from("-"));
    println!("2 - 3 = {}", minus(2, 3));
}
```

When I try compiling, I get these errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:9:40
  |
9 |     dispatch.insert(String::from("-"), |a, b| a - b);
  |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected closure, found a different closure
  |
  = note: expected type `[closure@src/main.rs:8:40: 8:52]`
             found type `[closure@src/main.rs:9:40: 9:52]`
  = note: no two closures, even if identical, have the same type
  = help: consider boxing your closure and/or using it as a trait object

error[E0618]: expected function, found enum variant `plus`
  --> src/main.rs:12:28
   |
11 |     let plus = dispatch.get(&String::from("+"));
   |         ---- `plus` defined here
12 |     println!("2 + 3 = {}", plus(2, 3));
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^ not a function
help: `plus` is a unit variant, you need to write it without the parenthesis
   |
12 |     println!("2 + 3 = {}", plus);
   |                            ^^^^

error[E0618]: expected function, found enum variant `minus`
  --> src/main.rs:15:28
   |
14 |     let minus = dispatch.get(&String::from("-"));
   |         ----- `minus` defined here
15 |     println!("2 - 3 = {}", minus(2, 3));
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^ not a function
help: `minus` is a unit variant, you need to write it without the parenthesis
   |
15 |     println!("2 - 3 = {}", minus);
   |                            ^^^^^
```

What does "no two closures, even if identical, have the same type" mean? How can I make a HashMap hold a closure, and then call it?

It sounds like using `Box` would fix it... Like I said, I'm pretty new, and I haven't used `Box`. How do I get what's in the box out of the box?

Comment: Can you explain what you find confusing about the compiler message: `no two closures, even if identical, have the same type; consider boxing your closure and/or using it as a trait object`? That way, we know how to usefully answer your question.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Expected closure, found a different closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39083375/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: I experimented with [a few different dispatching patterns](http://hg.mwdiamond.com/rivet), which you might find helpful / interesting.

Comment: @Shepmaster It does indeed look like a similar problem. Thanks for linking to it. I'd appreciate a clearer answer to my specific problem, though. :) I think that'd be valuable not only to myself but anyone looking for "dispatch table".

Comment: `consider boxing your closure and/or using it as a trait object` That's the right answer, right there. Give your hash map an explicit type that all of the closures can agree with.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo That sounds like it would work. How do I do that though? (I put that at the bottom of the question.)

Comment: If you are looking for the exact syntax, that question has two answers showing syntax. [What is the inferred type of a vector of closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29371914/155423) also does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few orthogonal issues here. First and foremost, your hashmap is immutable. You use `let` instead of `let mut`, which is good practice, but in order to be able to insert into it, we need it to (at least initially) be `let mut`. If you're planning to modify the hashmap after the initial construction, you may want to `let mut` the `dispatch` variable as well.

```
let dispatch = {
    let mut temp = HashMap::new();
    temp.insert(String::from("+"), |a, b| a + b);
    temp.insert(String::from("-"), |a, b| a - b);
    temp
};
```

Now you need an explicit type for your hashmap. The two closures you've defined, as far as the compiler is concerned, are of entirely distinct types. However, they are both *compatible* with `fn(i32, i32) -> i32`, the type of binary functions on `i32` (you can replace `i32` with a different numerical type if you wish), so let's make the type explicit.

```
let dispatch = {
    let mut temp: HashMap<String, fn(i32, i32) -> i32> = HashMap::new();
    temp.insert(String::from("+"), |a, b| a + b);
    temp.insert(String::from("-"), |a, b| a - b);
    temp
};
```

Finally, `HashMap.get` returns an [`std::option::Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html), not a direct value, so we need to unwrap it. `get` returns `None` if the key isn't found. If this was a large project, we'd handle that error appropriately, perhaps by logging it or telling the user, but for something simple like this, we simply need to use `expect`, which essentially tells the compiler "Yes, I know this could go horribly wrong. I'm willfully ignoring that fact." which is perfectly fine for our simple example.

```
let plus = dispatch.get(&String::from("+")).expect("Couldn't find +");
```

```
let minus = dispatch.get(&String::from("-")).expect("Couldn't find -");
```

**Complete example**

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let dispatch = {
        let mut temp: HashMap<String, fn(i32, i32) -> i32> = HashMap::new();
        temp.insert("+".into(), |a, b| a + b);
        temp.insert("-".into(), |a, b| a - b);
        temp
    };

    let plus = dispatch["+"];
    println!("2 + 3 = {}", plus(2, 3));

    let minus = dispatch["-"];
    println!("2 - 3 = {}", minus(2, 3));
}
```

Note that you can replace `String` with `&'static str`:

```
let dispatch = {
    let mut temp: HashMap<_, fn(i32, i32) -> i32> = HashMap::new();
    temp.insert("+", |a, b| a + b);
    temp.insert("-", |a, b| a - b);
    temp
};
```

Comment: `dispatch.get(&String::from("+"))` — unneeded allocation. `dispatch.get("+")` is fine to lookup. I don't know why the `HashMap` is `String`, but that could probably be a `&str` as well.

Comment: `hm.get(x).expect(...)` -> `hm[x]`.

Comment: `HashMap<String, fn(i32, i32) -> i32>` — No need to restate the key type; `HashMap<_, fn(i32, i32) -> i32>`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Or you can put the full type and use `"+".into()`