# Why does boxing an array of function pointers with `box` syntax only work with a temporary `let` binding?

Tags: rust

I have two dummy functions:

```
fn foo() -> u32 { 3 }
fn bar() -> u32 { 7 }
```

And I want to create a boxed slice of function pointer: `Box<[fn() -> u32]>`. I want to do it with the `box` syntax (I know that it's not necessary for two elements, but my real use case is different).

I tried several things ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6118ed2f7399c59604e7e3b8300d562e)):

```
// Version A
let b = box [foo, bar] as Box<[_]>;

// Version B
let tmp = [foo, bar];
let b = box tmp as Box<[_]>;

// Version C
let b = Box::new([foo, bar]) as Box<[_]>;
```

Version B and C work fine (C won't work for me though, as it uses `Box::new`), but Version A errors:

```
error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `std::boxed::Box<[fn() -> u32; 2]>` as `std::boxed::Box<[fn() -> u32 {foo}]>`
 --> src/main.rs:8:13
  |
8 |     let b = box [foo, bar] as Box<[_]>;
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types. Consider using the `From` trait
```

Apparently, for some reason, in the version A, the compiler isn't able to coerce the function items to function pointers. **Why is that? And why does it work with the additional temporary `let` binding?**

---

*This question was inspired by [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151073/how-can-i-store-function-pointers-in-an-array). I wondered why `vec![foo, bar]` errors, but `[foo, bar]` works fine. I looked at [the definition of `vec![]`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/57d7cfc3cf50f0c427ad3043ff09eaef20671320/src/liballoc/macros.rs#L38-L46) and found this part which confused me.*

Comment: It works when you introduce types: `box [foo, bar] as Box<[fn() -> u32]>;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like an idiosyncracy of the type inference algorithm to me, and there probably is no deeper reason for this except that the current inference algorithm happens to behave like it does. There is no formal specification of when type inference works and when it doesn't. If you encounter a situation that the type inference engine cannot handle, you need to add type annotations, or rewrite the code in a way that the compiler can infer the types correctly, and that is exactly what you need to do here.

Each function in Rust has its own individual [function item type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/function-item.html), which cannot be directly named by syntax, but is diplayed as e.g. `fn() -> u32 {foo}` in error messages. There is a special coercion that converts function item types with identical signatures to the corresponding function pointer type if they occur in different arms of a `match`, in different branches of an `if` or in different elements of an array. This coercion is different than other coercions, since it does not only occur in explicitly typed context ("coercion sites"), and this special treatment is the likely cause for this idiosyncracy.

The special coercion is triggered by the binding

```
let tmp = [foo, bar];
```

so the type of `tmp` is completely determined as `[fn() -> u32; 2]`. However, it appears the special coercion is not triggered early enough in the type inference algorithm when writing

```
let b = box [foo, bar] as Box<[_]>;
```

The compiler first assumes the item type of an array is the type of its first element, and apparently when trying to determine what `_` denotes here, the compiler still hasn't updated this notion – according to the error message, `_` is inferred to mean `fn() -> u32 {foo}` here. Interestingly, the compiler has already correctly inferred the full type of `box [foo, bar]` when printing the error message, so the behaviour is indeed rather weird. A full explanation can only be given when looking at the compiler sources in detail.

Rust's type solver engine often can't handle situations it should theoretically be able to solve. Niko Matsakis' [chalk engine](https://github.com/nikomatsakis/chalk-ndm) is meant to provide a general solution for all these cases at some point in the future, but I don't know what the status and the timeline of that project is.

Answer (score 3):

`[T; N]` to `[T]` is an [unsizing coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html).

> `CoerceUnsized<Pointer<U>> for Pointer<T> where T: Unsize<U>` is
>   implemented for all pointer types (including smart pointers like `Box`
>   and `Rc`). Unsize is only implemented automatically, and enables the
>   following transformations:
>
> - `[T; n]` => `[T]`

These coercions only happen at certain *coercion sites*:

> Coercions occur at a coercion site. Any location that is explicitly
>   typed will cause a coercion to its type. If inference is necessary,
>   the coercion will not be performed. Exhaustively, the coercion sites
>   for an expression `e` to type `U` are:
>
> - let statements, statics, and consts: `let x: U = e`
> - Arguments to functions: `takes_a_U(e)`
> - Any expression that will be returned: `fn foo() -> U { e }`
> - Struct literals: `Foo { some_u: e }`
> - Array literals: `let x: [U; 10] = [e, ..]`
> - Tuple literals: `let x: (U, ..) = (e, ..)`
> - The last expression in a block: `let x: U = { ..; e }`

Your case B is a `let` statement, your case C is a function argument. Your case A is not covered.

---

Going on pure instinct, I'd point out that `box` is an unstable magic keyword, so it's possible that it's just half-implemented. Maybe it *should* have coercions applied to the argument but no one has needed it and thus it was never supported.

Comment: Why would `let tmp = [foo, bar]` cause a coercion to `[_]`? In fact, [`tmp` has the type `[fn() -> u32; 2]`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ade10d51f16fa1781c64724fb9580619). And I'm also not quite sure that `Box::new([foo, bar])` coerces its argument to `[_]` just because of the cast. I would assume that `Box::new([foo, bar])` has the type `Box<[fn() -> u32; 2]>` until it is explicitly casted. (But you are probably right about `box` just being kinda buggy)

Comment: I believe a `let` binding is only a coercion site if it is explicitly typed.