# Why can't rust automatically infer the type of closure put in Vec?

Tags: rust

```
let c1 = || { "c1"; };
let c2 = || { "c2"; };
let v = [c1, c2];
let v: Vec<fn()> = vec![c1, c2];
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
```

Why the compiler cannot automatically infer the type of `v` in the fourth line of the code, but needs to be explicitly specified. But the fifth line can automatically infer the type of `v`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29371914

Comment: One more, perhaps this one will help you the most: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28151073